# How to solve lookup transform problem between frames?

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector-mapping, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using hector_mapping to create map of my room. I used openni node to get the depth/image_raw from kinect sensor, I then changed it to laser scan data using "depthimage_to_laserscan" and used that "scan" topic to create hector_mapping. When I run all of these in a machine it works fine and creates a map but when I run "openni_launch" and "depthimage_to_laserscan" on odroid and "hector_mapping" on my machine, I get an error the following error:
"lookupTransform base_link to camera_depth_frame" timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base frame". What does this error mean and how did it not occur when everything was running on same machine.?

My odroid and machine communicates over a wireless network. My machine runs ROS indigo on Ubuntu Trusty.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241826/how-to-solve-lookup-transform-problem-between-frames?/) by [Ros User](https://answers.ros.org/users/26709/ros-user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-08-16**:
Do you have a tf connection between your laser scan and your base frame. A node that publishes that connection to the tf topic ?

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-16**:
The easiest way to get what @patrchri describes is to create a URDF file and then use `robot_state_publisher` and `join_state_publisher` to publish the transforms automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are running on two machines in distributed fashion first be sure that ROS connectivity is fully working. It's important to test both directions, i.e. to make sure publishing and subscribing works. See [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/90536/ros-remote-master-can-see-topics-but-no-data/) for some info in case it does not.

If ROS connectivity works, the next thing to look out for are time sync issues between both machines. See for instance [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/11570/ros-time-across-machines/).

Another reason for things not working could be overloading the wireless network (i.e. if you try to transmit too much data).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0